# Difference between expectation of a random variable and of a function

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Starting from the expectation for a simple r.v. we have that:
$$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^na_iP(A_i)$$
from this formula it seems to me that the expectation correspond to the area of the r.v. X (that is, how we know, a function) where $P(A_i)$ is the length of the base of each rectangle and $a_i$ is the height.

Moving now to a continuous r.v. we have that $$\int X(w)P(dw)$$
what come in my mind is that now the base is given by $P(dw)$ and the height by the value that X could take, $X(w)$.

Is it correct? or is not true that the expectation it correspond to the area of the r.v.?

My doubt are given by the fact that I don't have only $\int X(w)$ as in a normal function $\int f(x)$, but now I'm also multiplying the r.v. (a function) with his density function

Comment: That is usually the way to define the expected value, yes. You can e.g. verify that for discrete measures the integral is exactly the sum you mentioned.

Comment: It can be proved that the expectation (if it exists) equals $\int xP_X(dx)$ where $P_X$ denotes the distribution on $\mathbb R,\mathcal B$ induced by $X$. Also that - if $X$ has a PDF - the expectation equals $\int xf_X(x)dx$. That might come closer to your interpretation.

Comment: @QiZhu therefore it is correct my interpretation of expectation as area? and could you tell me something more about the difference between $\int X(w) f_x (x)$ and $\int f(x)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $\int X(w) f_x(x)$ and $\int f(x)$ (there is no indicated measure). I wouldn't too much interpret the quantity as an area, I would interpret that each point gets a different weight according to $P$ with respect to this measure (in comparison to the Lebesgue measure). See also drhab's answer, for PDFs there is a convenient formula with the Lebesgue measure where you weight it against the density function.

Comment: @QiZhu indeed the interpretation of area seems not to hold, or better, if $\int f(x)dx$ (a ipotetical function) is the area underneath the function, how could it be also $\int xf_x (x) dx$ an area (where $f_x$ is the density f.)? because here i'm multiplying a function (the density) **with the value of the r.v.**. Therefore how could be the same thing?

Comment: But what I said in the initial question about simple r.v. seems to be correct (that correspond to the area). so I'm confused

Comment: Of course it‘s an area, it‘s the area of the function $x \mapsto xf(x)$. I‘m not sure if there is another convenient different description. I myself have not seen it in the probability courses I’ve taken. Perhaps somebody with more experience knows more about this.

Comment: @QiZhu yes, in these 3 hours I think that I got the point haha.. thank you for your answers